# A value of type 'AuthResult' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'FirebaseUser'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm implementing the google sign in method in my project using Firebase Google sign in option, when the add the below line in my code its throwing me the error like:

```
A value of type 'AuthResult' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'FirebaseUser'
```

Here's my Code:

```dart
final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn _googlSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();

Future<FirebaseUser> _signIn(BuildContext context) async {

  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
    content: new Text('Sign in'),
  ));

  final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googlSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =await googleUser.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
  );

  FirebaseUser userDetails = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).user;
  ProviderDetails providerInfo = new ProviderDetails(userDetails.providerId);

  List<ProviderDetails> providerData = new List<ProviderDetails>();
  providerData.add(providerInfo);

  UserDetails details = new UserDetails(
    userDetails.providerId,
    userDetails.displayName,
    userDetails.photoUrl,
    userDetails.email,
    providerData,
  );

  Navigator.push(
    context,
    new MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => new Profile(detailsUser: details),
    ),
  );
  return userDetails;
}
```

Can someone tell me whats the problem please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)` returns a value of type `AuthResult`, therefore you need to do the following :

```
AuthResult userDetails = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
```

The other alternative and the better one for your code, is since `signInWithCredential` returns `AuthResult` and since class `AuthResult` contains instance variable `user` of type `FirebaseUser`, then you can do the following:

```
FirebaseUser userDetails = (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
```

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/lib/src/auth_result.dart#L18

Comment: When i use this line of code its still throwing me error FirebaseUser userDetails = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).user;

Comment: user isn't defined for the class Future<Authresult>

Comment: i did it and its still the same.i have updated my code please kindly check

Comment: It should be like this `FirebaseUser userDetails = (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;`

Comment: Can you answer my one more question I'm really stuck in that from long time

Comment: What is the problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59455961/error-while-doing-firebase-google-sign-in

Comment: Please check it here

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution (caused by a type change):

Firebase has recently changed its type 'FirebaseUser' (which is depreciated now) type to 'User'. Try renaming the same in your code and that should be the solution. In my case it worked for most of the same errors.

Best